# How many child node i have in body

Tags: javascript, html, console

I have code HTML i i have problem with this:

```
<html><head></head><body><!--oneComment--><script src="index.js"></script><!--twoComment--></body></html>
```

And i Have javascript code in index.js:

```
console.log(document.body.childNodes.length) //2
```

When i run this code in firefox in console a get 2, why? i have two comment and one script element in body. Two commend and one script is 3 node, so why i get log 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is before the second comment in the DOM. Therefore the second comment doesn't exist yet when your script runs and you are left with only two `childNodes`: the first comment and the script.

Compare your result to the output of:

```
window.onload = function ( ) {
    console.log(document.body.childNodes.length);
};
```